# WSO2 Enterprise integrator dynamic mediation and routing

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 Enterprise integrator.Am using 6.1 here is my use case:

1. I have a generic API that I use to send data to partners who already have their own web services. I wanted to know how EI can receive the generic message(with 20 fields) from my API, do mediation and compose a new SOAP message composed of say 5 fields and send it to a registered URL. Each partner has his URL and format of SOAP input and the EI should intelligently compose the message according to the third party's format.

Answer (score 0):

You have described a complex use case, indeed the wso2ei is very good tool to solve it, but we don't know what is your knowledge level, what have you already done and what is exactly problem you face. So far it looks like 'I have a tool and I don't know where to start'. Is it so?

> I have a generic API with 20 fields is used for Instant payment notification. There are several partners who have their endpoints registered with us. Each endpoint and SOAP structure/fields are different. Some endpoints expect 5 filds, others 7, others 3, very dynamic. When a customer makes payment, he makes a payment to a given partner. I should instantly send payment notification to the partner to whom the payment has been made- through the provided endpoint(or registered URL). I dont know how exactly to implement this in WSO2 EI

I suggest you start with http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com as building blocks of an integration solution. You should be able to implement every pattern you need using the wso2ei. Or you could ask on the Stackoverflow more specific questions and you will get answers much sonner. As well WSO2 provides extensive documentation how to implement each integration pattern

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Enterprise+Integration+Patterns

Based on your description    you may need some content based routing  (calling different transformation based on the addressee) and message transformation (xslt or payload factory to transform request and response).

As a surely useful hint - to dynamically define the target service endpoint, you need to set the To header.

From high level question you won't get much more detailed answer

Comment: Thanks gusto2. May be for more clarity, my generic API is used for Instant payment notfication. There are several partners who have their endpoints registered with us. Each endpoint and SOAP straucture/fields are different. When a customer makes payment, he makes a payment to a given partner. I should instantly send payment notification to the partner to whom the payment has been made. This dynamism is what I dont know exactly how to implement it in WSO2 EI . But I will read your shared links to see how.

Comment: you can have a separate sequence to mediate for each partner and then the main service proxy to route messages to the approriate sequence (e.g. using switch or filter mediator).

Answer (score 0):

also you'll need to transform using payload factory or maybe xslt depending on your complexity.  Payload factory works well if its reasonably simple data